# Silverlight 4.0 - speed of image resize and compression

Tags: silverlight, image, resize

I looked through the earlier posts on the topic but did not find a clear idea for solution.

My dilemma is as following:

I have built a Silverlight 4.0 application for processing images on the client side (resizing and compression) before moving them to the database via web service. It works fairly well, I use FluxJpeg library for achieving desired processing.

The problem though is stress testing. In production environment I expect really large images to be processed (straight from the digital camera) and in large quantities. With large files (3 MB +) and large quantities (20+), my Silverlight app takes lot of time to process images and move binaries to database.

If you encountered anything similar in your Silverlight development and have an idea how to speed it up please share, I would highly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: I have finally developed the functionality with fair speed. Still using FluxJpeg library for that. I just want to mention one important detail here - if you are using VB.NET for your Silverlight development, be aware that so called shift operators (like "p>>29") don't work in VB.NET projects the way they work in C# projects even though syntax for them is the same in both languages. I had avalanche of exceptions about arithmetic overflow that was somewhat puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling GPU acceleration for the Silverlight control?

Here's a nice summary article - [Deep Dive into GPU Acceleration](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/discovering-silverlight3-deep-dive-into-gpu-acceleration.aspx)